# Manipulating string into taking in 1 character

Tags: c++, validation, menu

I know my method may be a bit awkward, I am trying to validate input for a menu so that ONLY a number between 1-6 is entered and nothing else is accepted. I have working code where I take input in as a string then change it into an int in order to use it in a switch case, but I know I can make it work more efficiently. Any ideas?

```
 void menu(double pi, char ssTwo)                                                           //menu for choosing a shape
{
    string choice;

    cout << "Welcome to the shape calculator!\n\nPlease select what you wish to calculate:\n\n1 - Area of a Circle\n\n2 - Circumference of a Circle\n\n3 - Area of a Rectangle\n\n4 - Area of a Triangle\n\n5 - Volume of a Cuboid\n\n6 - Exit the program\n\n ";
    cin >> choice;

    while (choice != "1" && choice != "2" && choice != "3" && choice != "4" && choice != "5" && choice != "6")
    {
        cout << "Invalid input, please enter a number of 1-6\n\n";
        cin >> choice;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    int choiceInt = atoi(choice.c_str());
    system("CLS"); 

    switch (choiceInt)                                                          //switch case for each shape
    {
    case 1:
        circleArea(pi, ssTwo);
        break;
    case 2:
        circleCircum(pi, ssTwo);
        break;
    case 3:
        rectanArea(ssTwo);
        break;
    case 4:
        triangArea(ssTwo);
        break;
    case 5:
        cubVol();
        break;
    case 6:
        exitSystem();
        break;

    default:
        cout << "Invalid input, please enter a number of 1-5\n\n";
        menu(pi, ssTwo);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ASCII values; you can check the char '1' against 49. So just threat the char as an numerical value

Comment: What's wrong with using`case '1'`?

Comment: @stark I just think that the while statement is too long, I'm thinking there's a way to make it more efficient. It might just be me being ridiculous, but it works so I will probably leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the char as an Ascii value; Check http://rextester.com/XKMJ90988

```
#define ONE 49
#define TWO 50
int main()
{
    char val = '1';

    switch (val)
    {
        case ONE:
        {
            std::cout << "1 was Selected";
            break;
        }
        case TWO :
        {
            std::cout << "2 was Selected";
            break;
        }   

        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid input, please enter a number of 1-5\n\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

## Update #1

Check: http://rextester.com/WWUM1166

If you read the value from cin into a char and not a string it will only take the first character; So if the user press '1asdfad' you will only have 1 in the char and you will work with the 1; if 'asdfasdf' is pressed it will read 'a' and an invalid input is displayed;

```
int main()
{
    char val;

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> val;

    std::cout << val << "\n";

    switch (val)
    {
        case '1':
        {
            std::cout << "1 was Selected";
            break;
        }
        case '2':
        {
            std::cout << "2 was Selected";
            break;
        }   

        default:
            std::cout << "Invalid input, please enter a number of 1-5\n\n";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a suitable way, the problem is if I enter a string where the first thing is a number 1-6 (e.g. 4ogjdifojg or 1ngsdffjsdiojf) then it will accept that, and I don't want it to be accepted because the user could have made a mistake.